# handling validation when doing multiple ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, playframework

the scenario is as follows, I have a new screen which is pretty much just a checkbox and 2 fields, these fields are optional when user is accepting to have the new function. the request calls for both these fields already existed individualy on other screens, they update tables and do validation on the input given.

The current version I have below is a bit of a hack to try get it working. The main problem I have is that if one or both of the field requests returns validtion error then I dont want RegisterUserForNewFunction to run as it will redirect to a new page. I'm guessing because they are async the if statment is trying to execute before they can complete. The app is also written in playframework if that helps, I am new to both so Im sure there is probably something I have overlooked.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$('#Update').click(function() {
    hide_error();
    var field1processed; 
    var field2processed; 
    if($('#checkbox').prop("checked") == true){
        addField1();
        addField2();
        if(field1processed == true && field2processed == true){
            RegisterUserForNewFunction();
        }       
    }
    else {
        prompt_reminder('checkbox must be clicked to proceed.');
    }

    function addField1(){
        if($('#form-field1').val() != ''){
            $.ajax({
                   url: '@{request.updatefield1()}',
                   data: { field:  $('#form-field1').val() },
                   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                       display_status('Successfull', 'field1 added.', function(){
                           field1processed = true;
                       });
                    },
                   error: function(response, status, errorThrown) {
                       function_error(response);
                   },
                   type: "POST"
            });
        } else {
            field1processed = true;
        }
    }
    function addField2(){
        if($('#form-field2').val() != ''){
            $.ajax({
                url: '@{request.updateForfield2()}',
                data: { field:  $('#form-field2').val() },
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    display_status('Successfull', 'Field2 added.', function(){
                        field2processed = true;
                    });
                },
                error: function(response, status, errorThrown) {
                    function_error(response);
                },
                type: "POST"
            });
        }else {
            field2processed = true;
        }
    }
    function RegisterUserForNewFunction(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '@{request.newFunction.create(user)}',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                display_status('Successfull', 'registeredUserforNewFunction', function(){
                    location.href='@{web.redirect.listPage(user)}';
                })
            },
            error: function(response, status, errorThrown) {
                function_error(response);
            },
            type: "POST"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd simply create a validation method that checks both of them for legality, and runs everytime an ajax call returns.  That way you avoid a race condition.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. was looking to avoid to not replicate stuff done in the call but looks like it will be the best way to go.